# Java - Avoid passing object reference to multiple places while ensuring its thread safe

Tags: java, class, oop, design-patterns

I have a class with variables and methods which is basically a utility class used across multiple classes for rendering an information(secretInfo) in String format.

Basically, depending on the need, the utility class is called and secretInfo is updated.

I have tried creating a static variable secretInfo and same is initialized at the entry point and gets updated across multiple places.

Only downside with the above solution is that this may not work in multi-threaded environment and I want to avoid creating static variable.

Is there a way to avoid creating static variable and at the same time utility object can be accessed across multiple places without passing the object reference from one place to another while ensuring that it works in multi-threaded environment.

public class secretInfoUtility {

```
public static HashMap<String, String> secretInfo;


public static String renderInfo(HashMap<String, String> secretInfo) {

    //secretInfo gets updated here

}
```

}

Note -Idea is to keep this utility class loosely coupled with the other classes.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the singleton pattern

Comment: @DevG Why do you want to without pass the object reference from one place to another

Comment: @DumiduUdayanga Since this is a utility class, I dont want it keep passing the object reference and hence changing the method signature of the existing methods and classes.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yeah, but its more than that .

Comment: Just saying: you understand that already making that field *public* is a really strang approach? Any other code could just come in and write even overwrite that static field without going through any of your methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it possible for this ti be immutable then do so. Always opt for immutability where you can. In this case, the problem you want to avoid is memory inconsistency due to changes to a shared resource among multiple threads. You can do this by creating a happens-before relationship with the shared resource. In this case, the shared resource is a Map which can be a ConcurrentHashMap which will ensure that all read and writes are synchronized internally.

```java
public final class SecretInfo {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, String> secretInfo;

    public SecretInfo(ConcurrentMap<String, String> secretInfo) {
        this.secretInfo = secretInfo;
    }

    public String reder() {
        // convert map to String, doesnt need to be synchronized
    }

    public void update(Map<String, String> update) {
        // atomically update the map
    }

}
```

```java
public class SecretInfoService {

    private final SecretInfo secretInfo;

    public SecretInfoService(SecretInfo secretInfo) {
        this.secretInfo = secretInfo;
    }

    public SecretInfo getSecretInfo() {
        return secretInfo;
    }

}
```

Example usage;

```java
class MyEntryPoint {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ConcurrentMap<String, String> info = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        info.put("hello", "world");
        info.put("foo", "bar");

        SecretInfoService service = new SecretInfoService(new SecretInfo(info));

        ClassWithServiceDependency clazz = new ClassWithServiceDependency(service);
    }

    static final class ClassWithServiceDependency {

        private final SecretInfoService service;

        private ClassWithServiceDependency(SecretInfoService service) {
            this.service = service;
        }

        void render() {
            String rendered = service.render();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. How do we plan to use this across the multiple places ?

Comment: One thing you could use is service locator pattern so that you can pass a singleton around where needed. An example with spring boot might be; @Autowired SecretInfoService service;

Comment: I got your point but we are not using spring framework in this project.

Comment: It really depends on how your project is structured. I really can't help you beyond the scope of the question without more context, sorry.

Comment: Lets say I am in another class called as RecordUpdater,  I have already initialized the SecretInfo  and may be updated the map also in another class . How do I access reference to the already initialized secretInfo using SecretInfoService. If I do new SecretInfoService () , I am getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Also, in case we decide to get the reference to secretInfo in another class, again we will have to initlize SecretInfoService in order to access SecretInfo  using getSecretInfo() ,which again will reinitialize secretInfo. I have tried making it as SecretInfo  as static and things works fine but I would like to know if its really thread safe.

Comment: The point of the SecretInfoService class is that it should be created once and then given as a dependency to other classes like RecorderUpdater for example. When a change to the SecretInfo object is made inside SecretInfoService all other objects in all other threads will see this change because it's synchronized. You would never re-create the SecretInfoService, nor would you re-assign the SecretInfo object, which is why it's final in the service. You simply modify the underlying ConcurrentMap that SecretInfo is composed of.

Comment: I just added an example, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @jason ,but my real intention was to avoid passing SecretInfoService  to ClassWithServiceDependency . With this change, we are basically tightly coupling all the classes with SecretInfoService .I just want to access SecretInfo just by calling get method.

Comment: Well thats kind of the price you pay for service pattern. It's also extremely easy to mock a service like this using Mockito and other mocking apis. Yeah so SecretInfoService can definitely expose SecretInfo via an accessor. I highest suggest you don't use the singleton pattern because if you're worried about coupling, good luck decoupling something with global access.

Comment: lol , thats true. Thanks for your help. I am accepting it as correct answer.